# database upload from localhost to live server problem

Tags: magento2, database

I'm trying to move mac localhost Magento 2 DB and site to a live server using phpMyAdmin import. I've exported this DB to an .sql file. When I attempt to import I get this error:

**#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause**

How do I correct this?

[image]

OK, I killed that error, now I'm getting:

[image]

What the? Is there some export / import setting I'm missing? I've never had this much trouble importing a DB.

I don't want to have to restructure the local DB out of concern for crashing the whole thing. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using outdated MySQL version. Upgrade your MySQL server to 5.6.5 or higher to fix this. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html

-- Updates --

Also, check system requirements for Magento 2 installation. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: OK, thank you B G. I guess I'll have to take this up with Arvixe. They're running  5.5 and I'm running 5.7 locally. Argh!!! Appreciate the feedback bro.